# how to create a Collection<String> out of a single String in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run this following line

`credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);`

and get this error:

`The method usingOAuth2(Context, Collection<String>) in the type GoogleAccountCredential is not applicable for the arguments (GoogleDriveProxeyActivity, String)`

I then changed the code to this:

`credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE.split(",")));`

but is there a simpler\neater way to send the proper type of param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of all the string constants in DriveScopes (in [the current version of the API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/constant-values.html#com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes.DRIVE)!) are single scope keys, not comma-separated lists. So, you should create any suitable collection - this is a nice way to create a collection of size 1 in Java:

```
Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
```

Comment: but won't a comma separated collection of one item looks exactlyt he same?  `{item1 }`

Comment: which line in the API you have sent can teach me  `are single scope keys` ?

Comment: `public static final String DRIVE "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"` <-- no commas in that string constant - it's a single scope key. As are all the others.

Comment: but won't a comma separated collection of one item looks exactlyt he same? {item1 }

Comment: Sure, but you asked for a simpler/neater way - that's what this is. The code you gave makes little sense and was probably written for an earlier version of Google's APIs (if I remember correctly).

Comment: This returns a List<Integer> for me?